# Is connectionString secured from appsettings.json by using singleton pattern?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, singleton

I am using Singleton pattern to access connection string from  appsettings.json because I want to use it from any place. It is a secure approach to access connection string?

the following code used to access it.

connection class

```
    public class Connection 
{
    public string LocalConnection { get; set; }
    public string ServerConnection { get; set; }
}
```

Singleton Pattern

```
public class ConnectionHelper
{

private static ConnectionHelper _connectionHelper;
private static string _connectionStrings;

public static ConnectionHelper GetInstance()
{

    if (_connectionHelper != null) return _connectionHelper;
    
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();
    
    _connectionStrings = config.GetConnectionString(nameof(Connection.ServerConnection));
    _connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
    
    return _connectionHelper;
}

public string GetConnection()
{
    return _connectionStrings;
}
}
```

DbContext Class

```
public class DbContext
{
    public DbContext()
        : base(GetOptions())
    {
    }



    private static DbContextOptions GetOptions()
    {
        var connectionStrings = ConnectionHelper.GetInstance();
        var connection = connectionStrings.GetConnection();

        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);
        return optionsBuilder.Options;
    }
}
```

Comment: User secrets are only for local development.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong about using singletons to store some configuration settings no matter if it's db connection string or something else.

The credentials are as secure as your `appsettings.json` file on the server.